# Can you open devtools with a windows store app?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to open the Chrome devtools with a windows app. For instance, I want to open the Microsoft Store app "News" and inspect the elements from within the app.

Has anyone achieved this?

Thanks.